# Memory management in window phone 8

Tags: memory-management, windows-phone-8

My app need to load image from web each time with provided category and it is working, the problem is memory, Image loaded in memory not being remove when next category image load and hence memory increases and the app closing with the following message-

**The program '[4036] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2005270523 (0x887a0005).**

The code is ---

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Error != null)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                return;
            }
            List rootobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(e.Result);

```
     int c = 0, x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rootobj.Count; i++)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            img.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            img.Height = 160;
            img.Width = 210;
            img.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill;


            BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage();
            string path = rootobj.ElementAt(i).ThumbnailUrl;
            bit.UriSource = new Uri(path,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            img.Source = bit;
   img.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);


            c++;
            if (c == 2)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = y + 160;
                c = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x + 210;
            }
            mainGrid.Children.Add(img);  
        } mainGrid.Children.Add(grid);
       }
```

and to remove i had tried these--

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rootobj.Count; i++)
        {
            Image image = (Image)mainGrid.Children.ElementAt(i);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;
            bitmapImage.UriSource = null;
            image.Source = null;
            bitmapImage = null;
            image = null;
        }

        grid.Children.Clear();

        mainGrid.Children.Remove(grid);
```

But it still crashes after few type of image selected.

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: or How to Remove Loaded images from memory?

Comment: Could you show a bit of your code? Especially the part where you load the pictures.

Comment: code sample is now available

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like the following :

```
grid1.Children.Remove(image1);
image1 = null;
```

Comment: i had added images on grid and that grid on another main grid; and to remove i used--  grid.Children.Clear();
            mainGrid.Children.Remove(grid);  But still memory increasing..

Comment: did you set image object to null ?

Comment: grid.children.clear() freeing some memory is there any need of removing all image and bitmap local object step by step????

Comment: as i think you remove object for collection of childrens of the grid not freeing it's location in memory

Comment: is it required?, since i had created image object locally and then on grid so not specified null explicitly.